# NgRx subscription is ignoring duplicates

Tags: ngrx

I have a strange thing happening that I can't quite figure out how to fix...

To test this out, I have created an action that takes in a string payload and a selector subscription.

My selector is:

```
const getLoginFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<LoginState>('login');
export const loginResult = createSelector(getLoginFeatureState, state => state.loginResult)
```

Action:

```
export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = LoginActionTypes.loginSuccess

    constructor(public payload: string) { };
}
```

and my subscription is:

```
this.loginStore.pipe(select(loginSelectors.loginResult)).subscribe(loginResult => {
    console.log(loginResult);
});
```

and I'm running these actions:

```
this.loginStore.dispatch(new loginActions.LoginSuccess("Test1"));
this.loginStore.dispatch(new loginActions.LoginSuccess("Test2"));
this.loginStore.dispatch(new loginActions.LoginSuccess("Test2"));
this.loginStore.dispatch(new loginActions.LoginSuccess("Test3"));
```

My console.log shows

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

It's completely ignoring the duplicated Test2.

Any help as to why this is?

In my NgRx dev tools, it says "States are equal", so I'm guessing that NgRx doesn't fire an event if the states are equal?  Is there a way to tell NgRx to ignore this and always notify my subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

A selector is memoized - see the [NgRx docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors) - when the input is the same it won't re-execute the projector.

Alex Okrushko gave a talk about this concept and how to tweak it to your needs last year [NgRx: Selectors are more powerful than you think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7GKnjGCXzU)